# Division with remainder - Polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra

> For a field $K$, we set $K[x]$ for the set of polynomials with the
>   variable $x$ and with coefficient in $K$. The notion of degree will be
>   taken as usual, that is, the greatest degree of $x$ that appears in a
>   polynomial. Given $f$ and $g$ in $K[x]$, where $g \not= 0$, show that
>   there existe two polynomials $q$ and $r$ in $K[x]$ such that $f=qg+r$
>   (division with remainder).

In the proof for integers, one looks at the set $I=\{a-bq\mid q\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, and uses the fact that $I^+=I\cap\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ is nonempty and bounded below (hence, has a smallest element).

For $K[x]$, consider the set $I=\{f-gq\mid q\in K[x]\}$. Note that if $0\in I$, I am done. It it possible to consider a similar $I^+=\{\deg(r)\mid r\in I\}$ and proceed like I would for integers? Are there anyone who is able to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g$ is a constant polynomial, then it is obvious. Hence we may suppose that $g=ax^m+..$ with $a \not = 0$, and $m\geq 1$. If the degree of $f$ is $\leq m-1$, we are done with $q=0$ and $r=f$. Now proceed by induction, using that if $f=bx^n+...$ with $n\geq m$ and $b\not = 0$, $\displaystyle f(x)-\frac{b}{a}x^{n-m}g(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq n-1$.

Comment: What should be $q$ and $r$ in the case where $g$ is a constant polynomial? I saw when K=$\mathbb{R}$, but not in the general case.

Comment: If $g=c$ non zero constant, write $f=c^{-1}fg+0$, hence $q=c^{-1}f$ and $r=0$.

Comment: Can there be an error in your argument? The statement also said that if $r \not= 0$, the degree of $r$ is smaller than the degree of $g$. However, if the field is $K = \mathbb{R}$, the polynomials $f(x)= 5x^5 + x + 1$ and $g(x) = 3x^2 + 5x + 1$ have as remainder $r(x) = f(x)-\frac{b}{a}x^{n-m}g(x) = -25*3^{-1} x^4 - 5*3^{-1} x^3+x +1$ but $deg(r) > deg(g)$.

Comment: The argument say that $f_1(x)=f(x)-\frac{b}{a}x^{n-m}g(x)$ is a polynomial of degree less than $n-1$. Now you can use the induction hypothesis on $f_1$ to finish. You can write $f_1=q_1g+r_1$  with $r_1=0$ or degree of $r_1$ $\leq m-1$, and you have the result. for $f$.

Comment: Should I act on $f_1$ a bit like to find the gcd of two integers with Euclid's Algorithm? That is, if $f_1(x) = cx^t+...$ with $deg(f_1) \leq n-1$, then $f_1(x)=f(x)-\frac{b}{a}x^{n-m}g(x) \implies f_2(x) =g(x) - \frac{a}{c} x^{m-t} f_1(x)$ with $deg(f_2) \leq n-2$ $\implies ...$ till reach $f_w(x)$ such that $deg(f_w) \leq m-1$.

Comment: Yes, this is the procedure to find $q$ and $r$ explicitely. The induction is only to prove the existence of $q$ and $r$.. (Your $f_2$ should be $f_1(x)-\frac{c}{a}x^{t-m}g(x)$). Try this procedure with your example in your comment $f(x)=5x^5+x+1$, take $g(x)=x^2+5x+1$ (to avoid the division by $3$).